# Communication via socket between android and vb.net

Tags: android, vb.net, sockets, wifi, communication

I'm trying to create an android application that communicates with vb.net, this communication may be by wi-fi, but the tutorials on the internet always mention sockets, could someone explain me how communication via socket works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to connect both devices and get their IP address. Then select a port number (a random number larger than 1000 and smaller than 65535 if you don't have preference). Then create sockets on both ends with the port number, and send packets to the counterpart with its IP/port number. That's it.

Comment: Thanks! The IP from my wifi is 10.0.0.1. And I could see in other applications, they make the communication by ip 10.0.0.101, can I use this IP but change the port?

Comment: Yes. Basically as long as you could ping to a device using an IP address, you can use this IP address in your socket communication.